# How can I draw the driver?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I need the same car figure as below, with a human. I need the idea of how can I start.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setupscalewithtikz[1][\linewidth]{%
\newsavebox{\box@tikzpicture}
\newlength{\newwidth}
\setlength{\newwidth}{#1} 
}
\NewEnviron{tikzpicture*}[1][]{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\box@tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
     \BODY
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\width@scale@picture{\newwidth/\wd\box@tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1,scale=\width@scale@picture]
    \BODY
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
      %\centering
      \begin{center}
      \begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{.8\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale, declare function={
              excitation(\t,\w) = sin(\t*\w);
              noise = rnd - 0.5;
              source(\t) = excitation(\t,20) + noise;
              filter(\t) = 1 - abs(sin(mod(\t, 50)));
              speech(\t) = 1 + source(\t)*filter(\t);
            }]
            \draw
            [draw=black,rounded corners=6ex,very thick] (3.6,0.5) -- (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,2.5)-- ++(3,0);% --  ++(15,0) -- ++(0,-2.5)--++(-2.5,0);
            \draw[draw=black,rounded corners=5ex,very thick](14.1,3) -- (16.1,3) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- ++(-2.1,0);


            %nicheni line 
            \draw[draw=black,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick](6,0.5)--(11.6,0.5);


            %\draw[draw=black,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick](1.5,0.7)--(1.5,0.5)--(3,0.5);

            %6aparu
            \draw[very thick, rounded corners=5ex,thick]  (4.5,3) -- ++(2,2) -- ++(6.6,0) -- ++(1,-2);
            %\draw[thick]  (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
            %\draw[draw=black,thick] (2.75,.5) circle (.5);
            %\draw[draw=black,thick] (5.5,.5) circle (.5);
            %\draw[draw=black,semithick] (2.75,.5) circle (.4);
            %\draw[draw=black,semithick] (5.5,.5) circle (.4);

            \draw [draw=black,very thick](6,.5) arc (0:180:12mm);
            \draw [draw=black,very thick](14,.5) arc (0:180:12mm);



            \draw[->,thick] (5,0.5)node[below = 1mm]{$1N$} -- (5,1.6);
            \draw[gray, dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (7,2.5) ;
            \draw[gray,dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (7,4)node[above]{2};
            \draw[gray, dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (10.5,4)node[above]{3};
            \draw[gray, dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (10.5,2.5)node[above]{4};
            %\draw[->,thick] (5,-0.5) -- (5,1.6);


            %\draw [draw=black,very thick](7,3.5) arc (0:90:2mm);
             %\draw [draw=black,very thick](7,3.5) arc (0:90:4mm);




            \draw[ x=0.0085cm, y=0.2cm, yshift=2.8cm, xshift = 7cm] (0,1) -- plot [domain=0:90, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{speech(\x)});

             %\draw[help lines] (0,1) -- (3,1);
            \draw[->,ultra thick](7,2.5)--node[below]{SPL}(8,2.5);
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (7,2.5)--(7,3.5) node[above]{};

            %\draw (7.5,4) node[anchor=south] {2};
            %\draw (10.5,4) node[anchor=south] {3};
            %\draw (10.5,2.5) node[anchor=south] {4};



      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}
      \end{center}

      \caption{Sensitivity analysis for cut Model of car}
      \label{fig:sens_1ncar}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. What have you tried so-far? Please show us your try, because, this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: And a short answer is you have many possibility to do-so. Right now I'm voting to close as this question as too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rough approximation with tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (3.7856,5.5772) .. controls (3.7649,5.5841) and (3.7443,5.5910) .. (3.7236,5.5978) .. controls (3.6435,5.5981) and (3.5057,5.6054) .. (3.4820,5.5903) .. controls (3.4642,5.5789) and (3.3646,5.4897) .. (3.3646,5.4897) .. controls (3.3189,5.4346) and (3.2563,5.3743) .. (3.2127,5.3172) .. controls (3.1246,5.3260) and (2.9900,5.3748) .. (2.9710,5.3436) .. controls (2.9551,5.2936) and (3.2106,5.1765) .. (3.2353,5.1850) .. controls (3.2703,5.1971) and (3.2750,5.2474) .. (3.2949,5.2786) .. controls (3.3259,5.3017) and (3.3657,5.3144) .. (3.3959,5.3396) .. controls (3.4361,5.3733) and (3.4899,5.3898) .. (3.5109,5.4431) .. controls (3.5248,5.4900) and (3.6682,5.3894) .. (3.7728,5.3737) .. controls (3.8695,5.3603) and (3.9837,5.3226) .. (4.0635,5.3788) .. controls (4.0925,5.3993) and (4.0952,5.4423) .. (4.1111,5.4740) .. controls (4.1278,5.5241) and (4.1232,5.5598) .. (4.1346,5.6116) .. controls (4.1537,5.6361) and (4.1974,5.6679) .. (4.2133,5.6960) .. controls (4.3162,5.8764) and (4.2474,6.0813) .. (4.2829,6.2472) .. controls (4.3078,6.2860) and (4.3491,6.3162) .. (4.3671,6.3594) .. controls (4.3792,6.3887) and (4.3899,6.4233) .. (4.3807,6.4537) .. controls (4.3692,6.4915) and (4.3386,6.5285) .. (4.3014,6.5418) .. controls (4.2877,6.5467) and (4.2725,6.5487) .. (4.2572,6.5481) .. controls (4.2317,6.5472) and (4.2060,6.5389) .. (4.1868,6.5242) .. controls (4.1232,6.4754) and (4.0778,6.3304) .. (4.0899,6.3039) .. controls (4.1031,6.2753) and (4.1463,6.2757) .. (4.1745,6.2616) .. controls (4.1730,6.2473) and (4.1425,6.2282) .. (4.1303,6.2121) .. controls (4.0720,6.1461) and (4.0206,6.1304) .. (3.9854,6.0496) .. controls (3.9392,5.9433) and (3.9313,5.7753) .. (3.9137,5.6608)(4.2045,5.9956) .. controls (4.1959,5.9440) and (4.1873,5.8924) .. (4.1787,5.8409) .. controls (4.1249,5.7272) and (4.0496,5.5164) .. (4.0106,5.5022) .. controls (3.9778,5.4902) and (3.8616,5.5518) .. (3.7871,5.5767)(4.0811,6.0484) .. controls (4.0429,5.9104) and (4.0048,5.7724) .. (3.9666,5.6343) .. controls (3.8631,5.6947) and (3.7597,5.7550) .. (3.6562,5.8154) .. controls (3.6100,5.8572) and (3.6110,5.8229) .. (3.5675,5.7896) .. controls (3.5395,5.7650) and (3.6549,5.6846) .. (3.8948,5.5358);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whole car:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
\def\tikz@width{#1}%
\def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
\BODY
\end{lrbox}%
\pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
\edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
\BODY
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setupscalewithtikz[1][\linewidth]{%
\newsavebox{\box@tikzpicture}
\newlength{\newwidth}
\setlength{\newwidth}{#1} 
}
\NewEnviron{tikzpicture*}[1][]{%
\begin{lrbox}{\box@tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\BODY
\end{tikzpicture}% 
\end{lrbox}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\width@scale@picture{\newwidth/\wd\box@tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1,scale=\width@scale@picture]
\BODY
\end{tikzpicture}% 
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%\centering
\begin{center}
\begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale, declare function={
excitation(\t,\w) = sin(\t*\w);
noise = rnd - 0.5;
source(\t) = excitation(\t,20) + noise;
filter(\t) = 1 - abs(sin(mod(\t, 50)));
speech(\t) = 1 + source(\t)*filter(\t);
}]
\draw
[draw=black,rounded corners=6ex,very thick] (3.6,0.5) -- (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,2.5)-- ++(3,0);% --  ++(15,0) -- ++(0,-2.5)--++(-2.5,0);
\draw[draw=black,rounded corners=5ex,very thick](14.1,3) -- (16.1,3) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- ++(-2.1,0);


%nicheni line 
\draw[draw=black,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick](6,0.5)--(11.6,0.5);


%\draw[draw=black,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick](1.5,0.7)--(1.5,0.5)--(3,0.5);

%6aparu
\draw[very thick, rounded corners=5ex,thick]  (4.5,3) -- ++(2,2) -- ++(6.6,0) -- ++(1,-2);
%\draw[thick]  (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
%\draw[draw=black,thick] (2.75,.5) circle (.5);
%\draw[draw=black,thick] (5.5,.5) circle (.5);
%\draw[draw=black,semithick] (2.75,.5) circle (.4);
%\draw[draw=black,semithick] (5.5,.5) circle (.4);

\draw [draw=black,very thick](6,.5) arc (0:180:12mm);
\draw [draw=black,very thick](14,.5) arc (0:180:12mm);



\draw[->,thick] (5,0.5)node[below = 1mm]{$1N$} -- (5,1.6);
\draw[gray, dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (7,2.5) ;
\draw[gray,dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (7,4)node[above]{2};
\draw[gray, dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (10.5,4)node[above]{3};
\draw[gray, dashed,->](5,1.7) -- (10.5,2.5)node[above]{4};
%\draw[->,thick] (5,-0.5) -- (5,1.6);


%\draw [draw=black,very thick](7,3.5) arc (0:90:2mm);
%\draw [draw=black,very thick](7,3.5) arc (0:90:4mm);




\draw[ x=0.0085cm, y=0.2cm, yshift=2.8cm, xshift = 7cm] (0,1) -- plot [domain=0:90, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{speech(\x)});

%\draw[help lines] (0,1) -- (3,1);
\draw[->,ultra thick](7,2.5)--node[below]{SPL}(8,2.5);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (7,2.5)--(7,3.5) node[above]{};

%\draw (7.5,4) node[anchor=south] {2};
%\draw (10.5,4) node[anchor=south] {3};
%\draw (10.5,2.5) node[anchor=south] {4};

\begin{scope}[scale=2.5,yshift=-135,xshift=0]
\draw (3.7856,5.5772) .. controls (3.7649,5.5841) and (3.7443,5.5910) .. (3.7236,5.5978) .. controls (3.6435,5.5981) and (3.5057,5.6054) .. (3.4820,5.5903) .. controls (3.4642,5.5789) and (3.3646,5.4897) .. (3.3646,5.4897) .. controls (3.3189,5.4346) and (3.2563,5.3743) .. (3.2127,5.3172) .. controls (3.1246,5.3260) and (2.9900,5.3748) .. (2.9710,5.3436) .. controls (2.9551,5.2936) and (3.2106,5.1765) .. (3.2353,5.1850) .. controls (3.2703,5.1971) and (3.2750,5.2474) .. (3.2949,5.2786) .. controls (3.3259,5.3017) and (3.3657,5.3144) .. (3.3959,5.3396) .. controls (3.4361,5.3733) and (3.4899,5.3898) .. (3.5109,5.4431) .. controls (3.5248,5.4900) and (3.6682,5.3894) .. (3.7728,5.3737) .. controls (3.8695,5.3603) and (3.9837,5.3226) .. (4.0635,5.3788) .. controls (4.0925,5.3993) and (4.0952,5.4423) .. (4.1111,5.4740) .. controls (4.1278,5.5241) and (4.1232,5.5598) .. (4.1346,5.6116) .. controls (4.1537,5.6361) and (4.1974,5.6679) .. (4.2133,5.6960) .. controls (4.3162,5.8764) and (4.2474,6.0813) .. (4.2829,6.2472) .. controls (4.3078,6.2860) and (4.3491,6.3162) .. (4.3671,6.3594) .. controls (4.3792,6.3887) and (4.3899,6.4233) .. (4.3807,6.4537) .. controls (4.3692,6.4915) and (4.3386,6.5285) .. (4.3014,6.5418) .. controls (4.2877,6.5467) and (4.2725,6.5487) .. (4.2572,6.5481) .. controls (4.2317,6.5472) and (4.2060,6.5389) .. (4.1868,6.5242) .. controls (4.1232,6.4754) and (4.0778,6.3304) .. (4.0899,6.3039) .. controls (4.1031,6.2753) and (4.1463,6.2757) .. (4.1745,6.2616) .. controls (4.1730,6.2473) and (4.1425,6.2282) .. (4.1303,6.2121) .. controls (4.0720,6.1461) and (4.0206,6.1304) .. (3.9854,6.0496) .. controls (3.9392,5.9433) and (3.9313,5.7753) .. (3.9137,5.6608)(4.2045,5.9956) .. controls (4.1959,5.9440) and (4.1873,5.8924) .. (4.1787,5.8409) .. controls (4.1249,5.7272) and (4.0496,5.5164) .. (4.0106,5.5022) .. controls (3.9778,5.4902) and (3.8616,5.5518) .. (3.7871,5.5767)(4.0811,6.0484) .. controls (4.0429,5.9104) and (4.0048,5.7724) .. (3.9666,5.6343) .. controls (3.8631,5.6947) and (3.7597,5.7550) .. (3.6562,5.8154) .. controls (3.6100,5.8572) and (3.6110,5.8229) .. (3.5675,5.7896) .. controls (3.5395,5.7650) and (3.6549,5.6846) .. (3.8948,5.5358);
\end{scope}




\end{tikzpicture}
\end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}
\end{center}

\caption{Sensitivity analysis for cut Model of car}
\label{fig:sens_1ncar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you find the solution? This human is looking exactly the same as I gave in the figure.

Comment: Can you show me how can I produce the command?